# htaccess - using quotes or not?

Tags: .htaccess

I read on stackoverflow often htaccess RewriteConds and RewriteRules without using doublequotes. However, quotes are always used in the apache docs. The thing works with and without quotes. But what is valid, also for the future? Is there a recommendation from apache somewhere?

Example with double quotes

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/images/(.*)_thumb\.jpg" [NC]
RewriteRule "^images/(.*)_thumb\.jpg$" "/imgthumbs/$1-thumb.jpg" [R=301,QSD,L]
```

Example without double quotes

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/(.*)_thumb\.jpg [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)_thumb\.jpg$ /imgthumbs/$1-thumb.jpg [R=301,QSD,L]
```

Comment: They are rarely ever needed. If you have to put a text literal that contains a space anywhere in there, then they must be used, for rather obvious reasons - [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/FAQ#FAQ-HowcanIusestringswithwhitespacesin'sENVflag?](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/FAQ#FAQ-HowcanIusestringswithwhitespacesin'sENVflag?) But other than that, most time you can do fine without them.